# Transitivity of Algebraicity of Field Extensions: the reciprocal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $k\subset K \subset L$ be field extensions.

If $K/k$ and $L/K$ are algebraic then $L/k$ is algebraic.
What about the reciprocal?

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to run argument at the level of individual elements. Also in the converse direction. By the way, isn't the converse rather easy? If  every element of $L$ is algebraic over $k$ then surely the same holds for the elements of $K$. And being algebraic over $k$ implies algebraic over a bigger field, no?

Comment: Right but what about L/K if L/k is algebraic? are all L elements algebaric over K?

Comment: Let $z\in L$ be arbitrary. Because $z$ is algebraic over $k$, there exists a non-zero polynomial $m(x)\in k[x]$ such that $m(z)=0$. Because $k$ is a subset of $K$, $m(x)\in K[x]$. Therefore $z$ is algebraic over $K$.

Comment: Thank you! it's clear now

Comment: Great! You are welcome to flesh out the argument as an answer. That way you get feedback on any residual unclear points (if any).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is mainly inspired from Jyrki's explanatory Comment.

Suppose L/k is algebraic.

Let $x\in L$. x is algebraic over $k$, which means : $\exists P\in k[X]: P(x)=0$.

But $P\in k[X] \subset K[X]$ so x is algebraic over $K$ and $L/K$ is algebraic.

Let $y\in K$. $y\in L$ so $y$ is algebraic over $k$ and $K/k$ is also algebraic.